# jQuery multiple class and nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a table which has multiple classes.

```
<tr>
<td class='one two'>One</td>
<td class='one three'>Another</td>
<td class='one example'>Yet another</td>
<td class='one two'>Yet another</td>
<td class='four'>Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='one two'>One</td>
<td class='one three'>Another</td>
<td class='one example'>Yet another</td>
<td class='one two'>Yet another</td>
<td class='four'>Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='one two'>One</td>
<td class='one three'>Another</td>
<td class='one example'>Yet another</td>
<td class='one two'>Yet another</td>
<td class='four'>Four</td>
</tr>
```

What I want is to set the **first** text from the every tr which contain the td has class 'one', no mather if another class is added.

I've tried with a classic example, but it doesn't work:

```
        var i=0;
   $(".one:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
    temp[i] = $(this).text;
    console.log("Result: "+temp[i]);
        i++;
     });
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: first of all you should to define an array in `var temp`  and the rest you have here http://jsfiddle.net/ktgrcL3r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$("tr td.one:first-child").each(function(i) {
  temp[i] = $(this).text();
  console.log("Result: "+temp[i]);
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: But I want only the **first** first text from every <tr> that contains class one. Or lets say second text.

Comment: @pbwned: is not it doing the same??

Comment: It returns **all** results (One Another Yet another Yet another Four). What I want to do is to set only the first one to the variable temp, so basically for this case, that would mean: only those who are **One**. So the result should be: One One One

Comment: have you checked the console in demo. it is logging three dom elements i.e. every first td element with class `.one`

Comment: The link you have posted returns the following results http://shrani.si/f/3t/ba/4nQZWdWR/res.png . I want only those marked with red.

Comment: that is not console,that is rendered html. just open the console using f12 then console and you will see that only the red one are captured. do you want to hide the rest from html??

Comment: It works. I overlooked console.log and focused on the output.. Sorry. Thank you guys!